# Sobolev variant of Wasserstein space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, sobolev-spaces, optimal-transportation, lipschitz-spaces

Let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of Borel probability measures on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider thereof consisting of all probability measures $\mathbb{P}$ satisfying $\int\, \|x\|\mathbb{P}(dx)<\infty$.   One can *identify* this as a subspace of the pre-dual of $\operatorname{Lip}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (via $\mathbb{P}\mapsto \mathbb{P}-\delta_0$) normed by $\|f\|_{\operatorname{Lip}}:=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\, \|f(x)\| + \sup_{x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}^n}\, \frac{|f(x)-f(x_2)|}{\|x_1-x_2\|}$ which we metrize using the restriction of the dual-norm
$$
d(\mathbb{P},\mathbb{Q}) := \sup_{\|f\|_{Lip}\leq 1}\,\int f d\mathbb{P} - \int f d\mathbb{Q}.
$$
What's rather nice is that the Kantorovich duality (essentially) identifies this norm with the Wasserstein 1 distance from optimal transport on the set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

---

Suppose that $k,p\geq 1, k\in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Define the norm
$$
d_{k,p}(\mathbb{P},\mathbb{Q}) := \sup_{\|f\|_{W^{k,p}}\leq 1}\, 
\int f d\mathbb{P} - \int f d\mathbb{Q},
$$
Is there a (somewhat well-studied or classical) metric $\tilde{d}_{k,p}$ on a (reasonable) subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for which there is a similar duality; or at-least
$$
d_{k,p}\leq \tilde{d}_{k,p}?
$$

Comment: When $k > n/p$ you can use Sobolev embedding to bound it from above by the Wasserstein distance for the metric $(x,y) \mapsto |x-y|^\gamma$ for suitable $\gamma \in (0,1]$.

Comment: By duality $d_{k,p}(\mathbb{P},\mathbb{Q}) = \Vert\mathbb{P}-\mathbb{Q}\Vert_{W^{-k,q}}$ with $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$ is the norm of the according dual negative Sobolev space of the difference of the measures.

Comment: @MartinHairer I don't fully see why?

Comment: @AndréSchlichting Here you're assuming that $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are dominated by Lebesgue measure no?  This I can't do since I eventually need one of the measures to be singular with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @TomTheQuant Since $|f|_\gamma \le C \|f\|_{W^{k,p}}$, the set $|f|_\gamma \le C$ is larger than the set $\|f\|_{W^{k,p}} \le 1$, so that distance is larger than (some multiple of) $d_{k,p}$.

Comment: @TimTheQuant: No, I assume that $\mathbb{P}-\mathbb{Q}\in W^{-k,q}$. By duality, this is the case once $W^{k,p}$ embedds into continuous function, on $\mathbb{R}^n$ this holds provided $kp > n$ by Sobolev embedding theorem.